# Unable to glue feature file with stepdefinition

Tags: cucumber

I've cloned a project from master (Git Repo) and I have got a feature file and corresponding step definition.I'm able to execute the tests through runner class and feature file as well. My issue is here, still feature file is showing to create a step definition. Could anyone know what is the problem here

Answer (score 1):

We are unsure about how your project project structure is but if you want to glue the step definitions then you need to add the cucumber runner and in the cucumber options you need to glue the step definitions as shown below.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"features"},
        glue={"helpers","stepDefinitions"},
        monochrome = true
        )
public class RunCukesTest{

}
```

Comment: Hi, I achieved this problem with updating the IntelliJ IDEA , Cucumber for Java and Gherkin plugins